# Fourier transformation in AdS space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, ads-cft

For flat spacetime $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we know

The fourier transformation of $f(x)$ is well defined via the kernel $e^{ik x}$. i.e.,
\begin{align}
\hat{f}(k) = \int f(x) e^{ik x} dx
\end{align}
what happens to ads space? If my points $x$ are in the bulk of Ads space, what can be Fourier transformation of my function $f(x)$ and what is the form of inverse transformation?

Comment: This kind of depends on what you are trying to do, but you are probably looking for the words "harmonic analysis on AdS space". Fourier transform is a decomposition into irreps of the translation group, and harmonic analysis is a generalization where you decompose into irreps of some other group, in AdS case the irreps of the group of AdS isometries.